# Internal links in PDF?

Tags: perl, pdf

I have been tasked with setting up a Perl-based document generator, and am considering using PDF::API2 and some of its additional packages (Simple, Outline, Content,...). I think I have most of it figured out, but there is one thing I'm still looking for. In an HTML page, you can set up a link (`<a>` tag) to go to another page or just to another anchor point within this page. Simple has an in-line link() method to go to external URLs, but is there any way to jump to an internal point (within this document)? I see that Outline has a way to set up bookmarks ("outline"), but my understanding is that it's just a collapsible tree navigation panel outside of the document itself.

I want to do three things:

1. Set up an overall navigation panel (probably using Outline) to page level anchors.
2. Set up links from one place to another to at random places within the document. This is *not* just to pages, but to points within pages.
3. Set up a Table of Contents with page numbers that are (if possible) both internal links, and (at a minimum) printable for hard copy use.

Furthermore, it would be nice to do this in one pass, which would require accumulating TOC entries (and other forward references) and at the end, going back to the TOC page and filling it in. I've seen hints in the documentation about doing this, but no concrete examples.

Can I expect arbitary PDF::API2::* packages to play together nicely, or are there known conflicts? Thanks for information and pointers to good documentation, including tutorials and FAQs that pull all the API2 pieces together.

================================= EDIT ====================================

Sigh. OK, let me rephrase this. In creating a PDF using PDF::API2 as the base library, I want to end up with 3 things.

1. Have my major headings be available as clickable links in some sort
   of collapsible navigation panel in Adobe Reader. I suspect that I
   can do this with "Outlines", but I have not found a good tutorial or
   clearly written working example. Is this documented anywhere? I
   can't examine much in a PDF file because it's compressed (Flate).
   Section names are preferred over thumbnails.
2. Have links within the document to arbitary places -- not just to
   section headings, and certainly not just to page tops. Think of
   HTML's `<a href="#target_label">target text</a>` and `<element
   id="target_label">` -- what is the equivalent in PDF? From looking
   around, it sounds like "Named Destination" might do what I want, but
   again, no documentation or examples to be found.
3. Have a Table of Contents with page numbers at the beginning of the
   document, in case someone wants to print it on dead trees. Given #2,
   I can probably brew up something on my own.

Is there **ANY** place that actually explains how to use these things, and gives some simple examples to get me going? Once I have the basic mechanisms, I can extend them to do what I need. Are there any PDF::API2 discussion groups/forums that are alive and useful? Thanks!

Comment: Add a comment to bump this into view. The more I read about PDF::API2, the more depressing it gets. _Everyone_ is complaining about the lack of examples/tutorials/documentation, and that the package seems to be basically unmaintained now. That would be a shame, as from what I've seen of it, it would seem to be a very powerful base to work from.

Comment: Just to update, Steve Simms has told me that he has taken over maintenance of the package, but has a lot of work ahead of him. I have offered to help with testing and documentation. It would still be nice to find even a crude "how to" for my specific needs here.